# ASP.NET javascript not executed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In the `C#` file, I have the code below, which transfers a file to the client:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SecurityPatch.exe.txt");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/images/SecurityPatch.exe.txt"));
}
```

In the `.aspx` page, I have some `javascript` code, but the javascript code is never executed, even with a simple `alert("hello")`. Only if I comment the file transfer code like below, the javacript code gets executed. Can anyone explain why this happens and how could I solve this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: i don't know where your javascript is being called, but I think you might want to look into the lifecycle of asp.net pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using content-disposition, you are outputting a file so the browser won't execute any JavaScript in the response because it is expecting the content of a file. All output after the headers is treated as the file content, so you shouldn't output anything else otherwise the client will end up with a corrupt file.

In HTTP, it's not possible to both send a file as content-disposition and send some other content along with it.

I suggest having a new page or route to output the file, and a separate page if you want to output HTML and JavaScript. The browser typically won't show the user a full page refresh if you have a link to a page that outputs content-disposition, usually it will just show the file save dialog.

Comment: Lol, this looks like a question from an exam. You nailed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing when to execute javascript code.

You should execute your code after the page has loaded.

```
function onLoadHook(handler) {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
  }
  else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", handler);
  }
}

onLoadHook(function(){ 
  alert("Loaded");

  // Do your work here. Create your ajax request and hook here. 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.The problem is the page disappears immediately after the file finishes downloading. Still this code doesn't work.